# Draw Heawood graph with tikz

Tags: graphs

this is my first question. I want to draw the [Heawood graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heawood_graph) using tikz. I don't know how to do a nice version like the one from the wiki picture, but I thought I could start instead by uniformly distributing 14 dots on a circle (with the actual circle line faded). And then draw the edges one by one. Any tips on how to start? Or how to do the nice one from the wiki pic?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is rather easy to draw something like this.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \node[regular polygon,regular polygon sides=14,minimum size=4cm,draw,yscale=-1] (14gon){};
 \foreach \X in {1,...,14}
 {\node[circle,fill,inner sep=1.5pt] at (14gon.corner \X){};
  \ifodd\X
  \else
   \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\NextX}{1+mod(\X+4,14)}
   \draw (14gon.corner \X) -- (14gon.corner \NextX);
  \fi}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Presumably there is a theory behind this, and you may want to look into the graph drawing libraries to generate these things more systematically.

Answer (score 4):

If you're working much with graphs like this you should use the `tkz-berge` package, which has many important graphs built into it. The code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tkz-berge}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}%
\GraphInit[vstyle=Shade]
\grHeawood[RA=7]
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

running in Gummi gives this output:
[image]

You can find the `tkz-berge` documentation [here](http://ctan.math.illinois.edu/macros/latex/contrib/tkz/tkz-berge/doc/tkz-berge-screen.pdf). There is another reference for more specific graphs using the package discussed 
[here](http://tug.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/tkz/tkz-berge/NamedGraphs/doc/NamedGraphs.pdf). The Heawood graph is on page 55. There are several built in styles for displaying the graph. In this case `vstyle=Shade`, the Shade style, was used.